# Authentication handling in Spring boot 2.x with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I am using spring boot 2.0.5 with below dependency for spring security of 5.0.8

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

I throwing a exception from the rest controller as below for test purpose.

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        throw new org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException("yoyo");
}
```

This is how the config class looks like,

```
    @Configuration    
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error");
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/error").permitAll();
        }
    }
```

I have added /error since spring boot documentation it says,

> Spring Boot 2.0 doesn’t deviate too much from Spring Security’s
> defaults, as a result of which some of the endpoints that bypassed
> Spring Security in Spring Boot 1.5 are now secure by default. These
> include the error endpoint and paths to static resources such as
> /css/**, /js/**, /images/**, /webjars/**, /**/favicon.ico. If you want
> to open these up, you need to explicitly configure that.

Add below in spring boot application class as well

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

When i hit the rest end point I get,

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-17T03:52:50.069+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/greeting"
}
```

But I expect status 401 with "message": "yoyo" like below,

```
{
    "timestamp": 2021-01-17T03:52:50.069+0000,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "yoyo",
    "path": "/greeting"
}
```

What changes I need to do for get that response

Comment: Do you mind sharing your ExceptionHandler and BadCredentialsException class.

Comment: I dont use any ExceptionHandler.

Comment: Activate the `DEBUG` level for the spring security package to see what's going on. Also your configuration is not exhaustive. You didn't specify anywhere that you expect the user to be authenticated before accessing the `/greeting` endpoint.

Comment: Why have you excluded the SecurityAutoConfiguration class? Are you trying to disable spring security to hit the endpoint?

Answer (score 4):

Add `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(..)` to get `Unauthorized` instead of `Forbidden` for `error` field.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/error").permitAll();

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, ex) -> {
            // You can add more logic to return different error codes
            response.sendError(401, "Unauthorized");
        });
    }
}
```

Define a new class that returns `ex.getMessage()` instead of `Access Denied` for `message` field.

```java
@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {
    @Override
    protected String getMessage(WebRequest webRequest, Throwable error) {
        return error.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-20T15:06:33.122+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "yoyo",
    "path": "/greeting"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't see the exception you have thrown because the "greeting" endpoint is secured and spring security handle it itself.

Set "/greeting" not secured so you can access it and get the custom error

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}
```